# Intermittent System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I have a console app that calls a WCF service to authorize scheduled credit card payments for a given store ID. Last night it called this service over 100 times and one of those calls, it got this error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to [service url] This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

What brought this to our attention was that this store had it's first 100 transactions authorized but 43 were left not authorized (not attempted). The service method simply grabs all 143 and does a foreach loop on them, authorizing them 1 at a time. The method returns a boolean result wrapped in a custom object that can also return error info if necessary, but that object should be small and does not change size in respect to the amount of transactions processed. I mention that because I read one case where this exception occurred in responses over a certain size. But it my case, it seems that something happened before it even tried to return. The service stopped processing in the middle of looping at which point the client received this exception. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the .Net Version? What are your service throttling configuration. Are you creating a new instance of proxy in for loop. Is your service Singleton? I might be able to help you if you can provide theanswers

Comment: It could be a timeout - how is the authorization done?  Via another web service call?  A database call?  As @Dhawalk said, without more information there's just too many possibilities to cover.

Comment: "This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down)" sounds interesting . I don't have access to the server but trying to have the logs checked.

Comment: @Dhawalk It's .NET 4.0. The whole service is pretty "cookie cutter". Service throttling is all default; not specified in the config. The mentioned loop is inside the service method so there's no proxy involved there. It's not a Singleton. It's using a custom UserNamePasswordValidator to authenticate against an ASP.NET membership db. I don't think it's a timeout at the client side because the results indicate it blew up, or otherwise stopped processing, in the middle of executing (during the loop). I'm happy to keep supplying info as you let me know what info is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: if the loop is in the server my only guess, could be that there is a problem running the batch in the for loop. My original thought was that this is client loop and 3.5's default throttling parameters were restrictive and 100 would blow it up

Comment: Oh ok. There is a loop there too where it calls the service over 100 times, but it does so synchronously. It creates a new proxy for each call to the service. Only 1 call had the problem and it was somewhere in the middle of the bunch. Those before and after did ok. Most of the contents of the service's loop are wrapped in exception handling that will let it continue. If the code that is not wrapped somehow threw an exception, could it appear in the form of this error message? I'll look into the throttling defaults some more.